# How to apply a and not b pattern match using regex in R

Tags: regex, r, stringr

I would like to filter a list by only keeping items that contain dimension or that contain metric and not penetration

I can filter to those that contain dimension OR metric and penetation, but I can't see how to switch the logic of the second case to metric and not penetration

Example below:

```
> library(stringr)

> var_list <- c("other", "dimension_1", "dimension_2", "metric_1", "metric_2", "metric_3_penetration")

> str_detect(var_list, "dimension|(?=.*metric)(?=.*penetration)")

[1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

Result that I would like to return from the `str_detect` is below:

```
[1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE TRUE TRUE FALSE
```

Comment: What is the expected result? With `str_detect(var_list, "dimension|^(?=.*metric)(?!.*penetration)")` I get `[1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE` - is it expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a combination of a negative and positive lookaheads for the second case:

```
> library(stringr)
> var_list <- c("other", "dimension_1", "dimension_2", "metric_1", "metric_2", "metric_3_penetration")
> str_detect(var_list, "dimension|^(?=.*metric)(?!.*penetration)")
[1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

The `^(?=.*metric)(?!.*penetration)`  regex matches when a string has `metric` and does not have `penetration`.

To only check for whole words, add `(?:\b|_)` boundaries:

```
str_detect(var_list, "dimension|^(?=.*(?:\\b|_)metric(?:\\b|_))(?!.*(?:\\b|_)penetration(?:\\b|_))")
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, why is `^` used as I thought this just specifies the pattern should appear at the start?

Comment: Yes, `^` anchors the lookaheads at the start. It is done for performance/efficiency purposes (only checked at the start of the string once).

Answer (score 1):

A logical combination of `grepl` calls is simple and involves no packages:

```
grepl("dimension",var_list) | (grepl("metric",var_list) & !grepl("penetration",var_list))
## [1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```